# Many to many partial view relationship in a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, partial-views

I have a button which add parent partial view and parent partial view also have a add button which adds child partial view in it.My problem is that when i press main button to add 2 parent partial view and press add child partial button in second parent partial view, then child partial view create in first parent partial view.I want to add child partial view according to parent partial view. How can i do this?

Coding

//parent partial

```
<div id="individual-details" class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        @(Model.SearchFirstName + Model.SearchLastName == "" ? "New Search Individual" : Model.SearchFirstName + Model.SearchLastName)
        @if (ViewData["hideRemove"] == null || (bool?)ViewData["hideRemove"] == false)
        {
            <a id="individual-remove" href="#" onclick="removeIndividual(this)" class="btn btn-danger pull-right">Remove</a>
        }
    </div>
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="card-block">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SearchPostcode, "Search Post Code", new { @class = "form-control-label" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SearchPostcode, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-block">
        <div id="Characteristics" class="mb-3">
            @if (Model?.Characteristics != null)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < Model?.Characteristics.Count; i++)
                {
            <div class="form-group">
                @{ Html.RenderPartial("IndividualSearchCharacterisiticPartial", Model.Characteristics[i], new ViewDataDictionary()); }
              @*  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Characteristics);*@
            </div>
                }
            }
        </div>
        <button id="add-characteristics" onclick="add(this)" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Add Characteristics</button>
    </div>
</div>

//Button 
function add(element){
               var action = ' @Url.Action("NewIndividualSearchCharacteristic", "Blended")';
               $.post(action)
              .done(function (partialView) {
                  $('#Characteristics').append(partialView);
              });
        }

//child partial


@model ABC.Core.Models.DTOs.Characteristic

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Characteristics"))
{
    <div id="characteristic-details" class="card">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="card-block">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-*-*">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, "Name", new { @class = "form-control-label" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-*-*">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Value, "Value", new { @class = "form-control-label" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Value, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-*-*">
                            <a id="characteristic-remove" href="#" onclick="removeCharacteristic(this)" class="btn btn-danger pull-right">Remove</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Get the unique ID of parent partial view where add button is clicked and add the child to that particular partial view.

Comment: Like how @PriyankPanchal is saying. Ensure that your ID of your div are unique and that the button when adding the parent partial is passing the new unused parent div ID

Comment: Could you post the related code to reproduce the problem? You could also set break point in the child partial button click event, according to your description, it seems that you are not finding the correct parent partial view to add elements.

Comment: i added the code, kindly check.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>   $('#Characteristics').append(partialView);
> ```

The issue is relate to this part of code, if you have added multiple parent partial View, there will have multiple `Characteristics` containers, then, if using above code to add the child partial view, the new items will add to the first partial view.

To solve this issue, you could according the trigger button to find the adjacent `Characteristics` container, such as: based on the trigger button to find the parent elements, then use find() method to find the `Characteristics` container:

```
  $(element).parent().find("#Characteristics").append(partialView);
```

Here is a sample, you could refer it:

Code in the main page (use a button to add multiple parent partial view (AddPost_PV)):

```
<button id="add_Post" onclick="AddPost(this);"  type="button" class="btn btn-success">Add Post</button>

<div id="parent_pv_container">

</div>
```

Code in the parent view page:

```
@model dotNetCore3_1.Models.Post

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="AddPost_PV">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Content" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Content" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Content" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button id="add_blog" onclick="AddBlog(this);" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Add Blogs</button><br />
                <div id="child_pv_container">

                </div>
            </div> 
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
    var index = 0;
    // add parent partial view
    function AddPost(element) {
        var action = '@Url.Action("AddPost_PV", "Blog")';
        $.post(action)
            .done(function (partialView) {
                index++;
                $("#parent_pv_container").append("<h4>Parent Partial View " + index + "</h4><hr />");
                $('#parent_pv_container').append(partialView);
            });
    }

    var childindex = 0;
    //add children partial view.
    function AddBlog(element) {
        var action = '@Url.Action("AddBlog_PV", "Blog")';
        $.post(action)
            .done(function (partialView) {
                childindex++;
                 
                $(element).parent().find("#child_pv_container").append("<h4>Child Partial View " + childindex + "</h4><hr />");
                $(element).parent().find("#child_pv_container").append(partialView);
            });
    }
```

The screenshot as below:

[image]

Comment: thanks, i solved it but the new problem is - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64224356/bind-another-model-to-partial-view-like-nested-partial-view-binding/64239732?noredirect=1#comment113597593_64239732

Comment: @UC57, It seems that Yongqing Yu  has already given a correct solution for that issue, please check it. If the reply is a correct solution, I suggest you to try to mark it as an accepted answer, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.