# bind another model to partial view like nested partial view binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a button which add individualSearch partial view and individualSearch partial view also have a add button which adds individualSearcharacteristic partial view in it.
I want to bind BMRTestData model with individualSearch partial so that i can get the characteristic partial view data. So i store that data in IndividualSearch's list  `public List<Characteristic> Characteristics { get; set; } = new List<Characteristic>();`

Please guide me to do same as i am new to .net .

Coding

//TestData(Main View)

```
@using ABC.Core.Models.DTOs
@model ABC.Core.Models.Api.BMRTestData



@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   
    <div class="card mb-3">
        <h5 class="card-header">Response</h5>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="card-block">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CompanyName, "Company Name", new { @class = "form-control-label" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CompanyName, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CompanyName)
                </div>
                
                <div id="searchindividuals" class="mb-3">
                    @if (Model?.IndividualSearches != null)
                    {
                        for (var i = 0; i < Model?.IndividualSearches.Count; i++)
                        {
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @{ Html.RenderPartial("IndividualSearchPartial", Model.IndividualSearches[i], new ViewDataDictionary()); }
                            </div>
                        }
                    }
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <button id="add-search-individual" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Add Search Individual</button>
                </div>
                

                <button id="add-company-characteristic" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Add Characteristic</button>
                
                
        </div>
    </div>   
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
}

@section Scripts
    {         
        function add(element){
               var action = ' @Url.Action("NewIndividualSearchCharacteristic", "Blended")';
               $.post(action)
              .done(function (partialView) {
               $(element.previousElementSibling).append(partialView);
              });
        }
    </script>
}
```

//IndividualSearchPartial

```
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("IndividualSearches"))
{
<div id="individual-details" class="card">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="card-block">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SearchPostcode, "Search Post Code", new { @class = "form-control-label" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SearchPostcode, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-block">
        <div id="Characteristics" class="mb-3">
            @if (Model?.Characteristics != null)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < Model?.Characteristics.Count; i++)
                {
            <div class="form-group">
                @{ Html.RenderPartial("IndividualSearchCharacterisiticPartial", Model.Characteristics[i], new ViewDataDictionary()); }
              @*  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Characteristics);*@
            </div>
                }
            }
        </div>
        <button id="add-characteristics" onclick="add(this)" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Add Characteristics</button>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

// IndividualSearchCharacterisiticPartial

```
@model ABC.Core.Models.DTOs.Characteristic

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Characteristics"))
{
    <div id="characteristic-details" class="card">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="card-block">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-*-*">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, "Name", new { @class = "form-control-label" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-*-*">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Value, "Value", new { @class = "form-control-label" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Value, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-*-*">
                            <a id="characteristic-remove" href="#" onclick="removeCharacteristic(this)" class="btn btn-danger pull-right">Remove</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

//IndividualSearch Class

```
namespace ABC.Core.Models.DTOs.Individual
{
    public class IndividualSearch
    {
    public List<Characteristic> Characteristics { get; set; } = new List<Characteristic>();
    }
}
```

```
namespace ABC.Core.Models.Api
{
    public class BMRTestData : BMRRequest
    {
       
        public List<IndividualSearch> IndividualSearches { get; set; } = new List<IndividualSearch>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to render the partial view directly or do you want to click the button first, and then display the partial view?

Comment: I want to display after button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

You can add onclick event in `Add Search Individual` button:

```
<button id="add-search-individual" type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="addSearch(this)">Add Search Individual</button>
```

Add an action in controller to return `IndividualSearchPartial` partial view:

```
  [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult IndividualSearchCharacteristic()
            {
                IndividualSearch individualSearch = new IndividualSearch() { };
    
                return PartialView("IndividualSearchPartial", individualSearch);
            }
```

Here is all the js in main view:

```
@section Scripts
    {
    <script>
    function add(element){
    var action = ' @Url.Action("NewIndividualSearchCharacteristic", "Default")';
    $.post(action)
        .done(function (partialView) {
            $(element).parents('#individual-details').find("#Characteristics").append('<div class="form-group">' + partialView + '</div>');
            ResetName();
    });
        }
        function addSearch(element){
    var action = ' @Url.Action("IndividualSearchCharacteristic", "Default")';
    $.post(action)
        .done(function (partialView) {
            $(element).parents('.mb-3').find('#searchindividuals').append('<div class="form-group search">' + partialView + '</div>');
            ResetName();
    });
        }

        function ResetName() {
            var index = 0;
            $(".search").each(function () {
                var nameIndex = 0; var valueIndex = 0;
                $(this).find(":input[type='hidden']").each(function () {
                    $(this).removeAttr("name");
                });
                $(this).find(":input[type='text']").each(function () {
                    if ($(this).attr("name").indexOf("Characteristics") > -1 && $(this).attr("name").indexOf("Name") > -1) {
                        $(this).attr("name", "IndividualSearches[" + index + "].Characteristics[" + nameIndex + "].Name");
                        nameIndex++;
                        return;
                    }
                    if ($(this).attr("name").indexOf("Characteristics") > -1 && $(this).attr("name").indexOf("Value") > -1) {
                        $(this).attr("name", "IndividualSearches[" + index + "].Characteristics[" + valueIndex + "].Value");
                        valueIndex++;
                        return ;
                    }
                    if ($(this).attr("name").indexOf("IndividualSearches") > -1) {
                        $(this).attr("name", "IndividualSearches[" + index + "].SearchPostcode");
                        return;

                    }
                });
                index++;
            })
        } 
    </script>
}
```

After submit, it will enter into following action to receive BMRTestData  data:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult TestData(BMRTestData bMRTest)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Here is the test result:

[image]

Comment: thanks, but i am not getting characteristic data in my model and in BMRTestData.

Comment: @Upkar, in your main view also has two buttons. Do you want to click these two buttons to add different partial views separately without data?  Please elaborate it.

Comment: if i click individual button, it opens individual partial view and in it, add characteristic button open n partial view, and repeat this again so another individual partial view having n characteristic. I want characteristic data of all individual partial according to individual.

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you able to get seperate data of all characteristics as per individual because when i enter my characteristic data and set a breakpoint in model characteristic class, it show null.

Comment: @UC57, when you click submit button, you want to receive `BMRTestData` model in the action which will get all data in the current view,right?

Comment: @UC57, the key of this issue is to change the name attribute of these input, so I create a js function to reset their name each time when you add input, I have updated my reply.

Comment: can you do me a favor, i am ban to ask question here. Can you upvote my some negative post so that i will ask again my queries? I am very thankful to you.